# Why isn't streamlit running in VScode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, streamlit

I installed streamlit in VScode, and tried to run this.

```
import streamlit as st
st.title("Hello")
```

But I dont get streamlit to pop up in a new browser, instead I get this message in the terminal. Is this something to do with my files?

Warning: to view this Streamlit app on a browser, run it with the following
command:

```
streamlit run c:\Users\MyName\Documents\VS code\test.py [ARGUMENTS]
```

Comment: how are you running it? Streamlit is a python module and has a specific command to run it.

Comment: What do you mean? I wrote the command st.title. I tried using various IDE's and I am getting the same error message

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.streamlit.io/library/get-started/main-concepts.

Answer (score 3):

I've face the same issue. Then, solve it by following methods:

1. First you install properly streamlit package with `pip install streamlit`
   then, go to terminal and run this

   `python -m streamlit run your_script.py`

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to run `Streamlit` code in `VSCode`.
This enables utilizing the debugging features of `VSCode`.

Update the `launch.json` file with the following:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        

        {
            "name": "Python:Streamlit",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "streamlit",
            
            "args": [
                
                "run",
                "${file}"
            ]
        }
     ]
}
```

Make sure the `VSCode` is configured with the right `python` `environment`.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion, just execute the `streamlit run c:\Users\MyName\Documents\VS code\test.py` in the terminal directly.

Comment: I tried that. I got this error message afterwards                                                            
 streamlit : The term 'streamlit' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ streamlit run test.py
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (streamlit:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @applesbanana_code This message indicates you have not installed the `streamlit` module in the environment which you are running. But when you run the python file, it prompts you to execute `streamlit run xxx`, which means you have installed the `streamlit` module. So it's a little weird. `streamlit` should exist in the `{python environment path}\Scripts` folder, you can through `get-command streamlit` in the powershell to get it.

Comment: You can try to restart VSCode or take Ctrl+Shift+` shortcut to create a new terminal that activates the corresponding python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't running VS Code from the Anaconda Navigator where streamlit is downloaded. Simply open VS Code from the Anaconda Navigator and it'll work or run **conda activate base** on terminal before running **streamlit run app.py**

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use vscode, you can refer to the documentation,
[How to use Streamlit with VS Code](https://awesome-streamlit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vscode.html).

If you directly run streamlit application in vscode without the above settings, vscode thought you want to run the command`python yourfile.py`, however, your expectation command is `streamlit run yourfile.py`. This is why the warning message you got.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample snippet of how to run a streamlit.py file. To get started, I'd suggest creating a virtual environment via conda (using virtual environments for python projects are a huge help):

```
conda create --name streamlit_env python=3.9
conda activate streamlit_env
```

Once an environment is created and activated, make sure to install streamlit.

```
pip install streamlit
```

Finally, change directory to your streamlit app and enter in the streamlit run function!

```
cd path_to_streamlit_directory
streamlit run your_streamlit_file.py
```

Answer (score -1):

```
python -m streamlit run app.py
```